# What does the ((->) r) mean in instance Applicative ((->) r) where?

Tags: haskell

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
```

This is the implementation of the Applicative typeclass for a function in Haskell.  I don't really understand the `((->) r)` and how to read it.

*I think it means it is a function that takes one parameter and returns anything (another curried function, a String) but I'm not sure, is that right.  Would that not be (r ->)*

Comment: When looking at regular operators, `(1+)` and `(+) 1` mean the same thing, right?

Comment: Your explanation is correct. We don't write it as `(r ->)` because there is no [section syntax](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5) for type operators (i.e. for no deep reason).

Comment: @Ry- Yup, they do (as opposed to `(+1)`, which amounts to `\x -> x + 1`).

Comment: The other comments and answers give you the detail and how this syntax fits in with Haskell generally, but in terms of "what does this mean", `(->) r` is a type constructor for all functions whose argument is a value of type `r`. So given a type `a`, this type constructor gives you the type of all functions `r -> a`, where `r` is a fixed type. (It's not just an applicative, it's also a monad, known as the "reader monad" because it allows you to "read" data of the type `r`.)

Comment: Ok! So, -> surrounded by brackets like (->) takes the type level operator out of infix notation and into prefix notation.  The r is just the first parameter of a function this then satisfies the definition of a functor of type function and allows us to do functor like operations on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, `->` is a type-level operator; it takes two types and returns a new type (the function type). In `((->) r`, it's partially applied, so you can think of it as a type-level function that takes one type `a` and returns the type of functions that take an `r` and returns an `a`.

```
((->) r) a == (->) r a  -- function application is left-associative
           == r -> a    -- switch to infix notation
```

You *could* say `(r ->)`, except Haskell doesn't support type-level sections. (And I don't *think* there is a GHC extension to enable such support.)

There isn't really a good way to read it, because it exists at a level of abstraction that isn't talked about commonly enough to merit a natural language description.

Comment: On "a good way to read it", in this specific case some variation of "functions from `r`"  might do the trick sometimes.

Comment: That's pretty imprecise; I'd use the same phrase to (more accurately) refer to the polymorphic type `r -> a`.

Comment: I was mostly thinking of turns of phrase like "the functions-from-`r` type constructor", or, say, "the functions-from-`r` `Functor`" (if that is the aspect one is interested in, and if the specific choice of `r` matters).

Comment: Could I say ((->) r) is all functions with at least one parameter?

Comment: @orangesherbert That's not a very good way to look at it.  At a very technical level, all functions in Haskell have exactly one parameter.  And that definition works at precisely that technical of a level.

Comment: thanks @Carl, so could I say ((->) r) matches all functions in Haskell?  (I thought no parameter functions in Haskell were allowed but they are not)

Comment: `(->) r` is a function, but not the kind you are thinking of. It doesn't have a type at all, but a *kind*, specifically `* -> *`. Its argument is something of kind `*` (aka, a concrete type), and it returns another concrete type. For a fixed `r`, you can think of it as the *constructor* of all function types that have `r` as their argument type. For example, `(->) Int` is the constructor for the types `Int -> Int`, `Int -> Char`, `Int -> IO Float`, `Int -> (Int -> Int)`, etc.